# JSON string to C++ object from class

Tags: c++, json, oop, object, header-files

Given a class definition as a header file such as:

```
class myClass {  

  private:        
    int data1;  
    int data2;  

  public:
    int getData1();
    void setData1(int);
    int getData2();
    void setData2(int);
}
```

and a JSON string like:

```
"{
  "data1": 5,
  "data2": 12
}"
```

is there any way to create a C++ object from myClass and set the data members with the values from the JSON string?

I have a lot of different classes with a lot of different data types as members, so something where I don't need to go through and code for each one would be preferred.

Comment: I do not really understand your question. I guess you can use a JSON parser (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245973/whats-the-best-c-json-parser) and the adapt the data to your class. That is what people always do. Or you can write your own parser, but it is not worthy the effort.

Comment: I gather you're asking if there's a Jackson-like parser for C++ that will convert JSON directly into C++, without you having to write any code.  I kind of doubt it.  But it's really not that hard to write your own constructor that accepts a JSON map object and populates an object.

Comment: try http://casablanca.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

C++ is not a dynamic language, you cannot use a way of Reflection in C#/Java/.. 
However you can use a way as Hot Licks suggested, just create a factory and parse the input JSON string, create the object.